# How to remove / prevent symmetric solutions

Tags: prolog

I am defining a rule like this:

```
person(p1).
person(p2).

near(X,Y) :-
  person(X),
  person(Y),
  checkNear.       % Not important how
```

I check that both `X` and `Y` are people and then I check if they are near (it is more complicated than this, but I simplified).

The problem is that I obtain a symmetric solution:

```
?- near(X,Y).
X = p1, Y = p2 ;
X = p2, Y = p1.
```

How would you force one solution per pair in this scenario?

Just asking for one solution is not an option because there could be a person `p3` to consider.

Comment: Would the predicate need to output `true` for both `near(p1,p2)` and `near(p2,p1)`, even though it only returns one of them for `near(A,B)`. Or is returning `false` for `near(p2,p1)` acceptable for what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easier way it's to use  standard order of terms [@<](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28@%3C%29/2)

```
near(X, Y) :-
  person(X),
  person(Y),
  X @< Y,  % arbitrary, but breaks symmetry
  checkNear.
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is just to check whether X and Y are persons, it would not be necessary to remove the mirrored examples.

But when you want to generate the possible solutions, you can use the solution provided by @CapelliC or you can generate a list of tuples of persons that qualify for X and Y like so:

```
findall((X,Y), (person(X),person(Y), X\==Y),R).
```

Then you need to remove the mirrored tuples like so:

```
removedup([(X,Y)|[]],[(X,Y)]).    
removedup([(X,Y)|L],R) :-
    removedup(L,R1),
    (member((Y,X),R1) ->
        R = R1;
        append([(X,Y)],R1,R)
    ).
```

You can than use this list further. For example:

```
checkNearAll([(List,Of)|Tuples]):-
    checkNear(List,Of).
```

Hope this helps in any way.